# recurrence relation-iteration method

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to solve this recurrence relation:

$T(n)=T(n-1)+ \frac{n}{log(n)}$.

I have tried this: $T(n-1)=T((n-1)-1)+ \frac{n-1}{log(n-1)} + \frac{n}{log(n)}=T(n-2)+\frac{n-1}{log(n-1)}+\frac{n}{log(n)}$

Hence, $T(n-i)=T(n-i-1)+\sum_{k=0}^i\frac{n-k}{log(n-k)}$.

$n-i=1=>i=n-1$.

$T(1)=T(n-(n-1)-1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{log(n-k)}=T(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{log(n-k)}$.

I don't know how to proceed. any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have an initial condition?

Comment: HI! this is T(1)=1

Comment: By induction it's clear that
$$
T(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac k{\log k},\ n\geqslant 2,
$$
but I don't know of any closed form for that sum.

Comment: @Math1000 There is no closed form but one can deduce the equivalent $$T(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\right)$$